# Camel blueprint <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="_setHeader1"><el>${header.uriPattern}</el></setHeader> waiting for dependencies

Tags: apache-camel, el, apache-karaf

I have the following Camel Context.

```
<camelContext id="_camuatomicservicecontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
        <route id="_camuatomicserviceroute1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="direct-vm:camuatomicservice">
                <description>accepts vm messages directly </description>
            </from>
            <log id="_log1" message="Camu Atomic Service body = ${body}, header= ${header.uriPattern}"/>
            <!-- <to id="_to1" uri="restlet:protocol:localhost:8189/"/> -->
            <setHeader headerName="api.key" id="_setHeader1">
                <constant>replace later with properties api.key Does not matter for this poc</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setHeader headerName="CamelHttpPath" id="_setOutHeader1">
                <el>${header.uriPattern}</el>
            </setHeader>
            <to id="_to1" pattern="InOut" uri="netty4-http:http:localhost:8189/path"/>
            <log id="_log2" message="CamuAtomicService Response body ${body}"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
```

From the documentation I expect the CamelHttpPath header to override the endpoint configuration "/path" such that calling Facade Services can pass the header.uriPattern in and dynamically change the resource they want to access. The bundle worked fine until I added the setHeader for CamelHttpPath and now getting "Waiting for dependencies."  I assume I need to install a feature, but Simple EL in other bundles on that server work already so not sure what feature I need to install.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  I used  and it worked fine.  The choice was farther down in the options.